# Show battery percentage on lock screen macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, monterey

How can I show the battery percentage on the lock screen in macOS Monterey?

When I turn my computer on or wake it from sleep and it prompts me for my password, this screen only shows me an icon of the battery in the top right, but no battery percentage like I normally see in my menu bar.

How can I make it show me battery percentage too?

Comment: Nothin has changed since you asked the same question regarding Big Sur. You didn't accept the answer that time, I don't expect you will accept it this time. You could just modify the previous question to cover Monterey.